# Wildcard replacements for the content in { } in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have an XML file with thousands of items:

```
<item  component="ComponentInfo{www.jne.co.id/www.jne.co.id.JNEwelcome}" drawable="app_jneexpressacrossnations_www_jne_co_id"/>
<item  component="ComponentInfo{xeed.xposed.cbppmod/xeed.xposed.cbppmod.Launch}" drawable="app_pbmc_xeed_xposed_cbppmod"/>
<item  component="ComponentInfo{xeed.xposed.cbppmod/xeed.xposed.cbppmod.Launcher}" drawable="app_pbmc_xeed_xposed_cbppmod"/>
<item  component="ComponentInfo{yong.app.music.android/org.kreed.vanilla.LibraryActivity}" drawable="app_music_yong_app_music_android"/>
<item  component="ComponentInfo{yqtrack.app/yqtrack.ui.splash.SplashActivity}" drawable="app_17track_yqtrack_app"/>
<item  component="ComponentInfo{yqtrack.app/yqtrack.app.activities.SplashActivity}" drawable="app_17track_yqtrack_app"/>
<item  component="ComponentInfo{yqtrack.app/yqtrack.app.UserInterface.Splash.SplashActivity}" drawable="app_17track_yqtrack_app"/>
<item  component="ComponentInfo{yuku.alkitab/yuku.alkitab.base.IsiActivity}" drawable="app_alkitab_yuku_alkitab"/>
```

But I need the result on all items as:

```
<item drawable="app_jneexpressacrossnations_www_jne_co_id"/>
<item drawable="app_pbmc_xeed_xposed_cbppmod"/>
<item drawable="app_pbmc_xeed_xposed_cbppmod"/>
<item drawable="app_music_yong_app_music_android"/>
<item drawable="app_17track_yqtrack_app"/>
<item drawable="app_17track_yqtrack_app"/>
<item drawable="app_17track_yqtrack_app"/>
<item drawable="app_alkitab_yuku_alkitab"/>
```

I tried doing this with regex but can't figure it out.  How can I accomplish this in Notepad++?

Answer (score 0):

In the `Replace` option (Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>), try with the below options:

```
Find What: (component).*?(drawable)
Replace with: \2

Search Mode: Regular Expression
```

And apply `Replace all` it will return your expected result.

Sample execution screenshot:

[image: Replace Nodes]

---

**UPDATE**:

There is two spaces in between the `<item  component=` if you want to remove that extra space, add a space in front of the `(component).*?(drawable)` finding string.

Comment: Almost right. You need to add a <space> before `(component)` to remove the extra space.

Comment: @图比图比 Could you [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/312043), so it informs others that your issue is resolved

Comment: @DavidPostill: Updated in the answer.